# Rails 6 alpha: Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails Alpha 6 is having issue with detecting the stylesheets. For which I have provided below steps to reproduce.

Steps to reproduce

```
1) Create Rails 6 app

2) yarn add onsenui
Add below lines to "app/assets/stylesheets/application.css"

 *= require onsenui/css/onsenui
 *= require onsenui/css/onsen-css-components

3) Create a sample view as below
```

Sign in

```
4) Access that page
```

Expected behavior

Page should render without error.
Actual behavior

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0.alpha application starting in development
=> Run rails server --help for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...

    Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
    Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    Environment: development
    Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
    Started GET "/pages/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-02 12:17:55 +0530
    (5.7ms) SELECT sqlite_version(*)
    Processing by PagesController#auth as HTML
    Rendering pages/auth.html.erb within layouts/application
    Rendered pages/auth.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.9ms | Allocations: 350)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 377ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 287951)

ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'onsenui/css/onsenui' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths:
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/fooapp/app/assets/config
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/fooapp/app/assets/images
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/fooapp/app/assets/stylesheets
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/rails/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts
/home/smitha/Documents/kiran/rails/actionview/app/assets/javascripts
/home/smitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts):
5: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6: <%= csp_meta_tag %>
7:
8: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
10:
11:

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8
```

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding "Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')" to config/initializers/assets.rb.